# Anyone suggest the deployment tool for .net web application?

Tags: asp.net, automated-deploy

Stack friends,

My company is following agile development process. We plan to do automate the .net application release management process. And we are new for deployment a tool which is following in industry.  Pls anyone give you valuable tips and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Many people use [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) for builds and deployment, but [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is becoming increasingly popular over the past few years as Microsoft has continued to add functionality. I'd recommend MSBuild. You can write a series of MSBuild scripts and surround them with a little bit of custom programming that executes them at given intervals or when certain events occur. If you don't want to build around MSBuild or NAnt as it is pretty low-level sometimes, a full product like [CruiseControl](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) will also work and might be easier for you to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Team Build: after a build is done you can easily deploy the output or let the build script do this for you.